# Proof verification that Gamma distribution converges in distribution to a standard normal. Shorter solution?

Tags: probability, proof-verification

> Let $X_n \sim \text{Gamma}(n, \lambda)$, with $n \in \mathbb N$ and $\lambda
>  > 0$. Let $Y_n = a_n(X_n - b_n)$ with $a_n, b_n \in \mathbb R$. Find $a_n$ and
>   $b_n$ such that $Y_n$ converges in distribution to a standard normal.

Convergence in distribution is equivalent to convergence of characteristic
functions; we have to prove that
$$\Phi_{Y_n}(t) \to \Phi_{\mathcal N(0, 1)}(t) = e^{-\frac12 t^2}$$

We have
$$\Phi_{X_n}(t) = {\left(\frac{\lambda}{\lambda - it}\right)}^n$$
and since $Y_n = a_n X_n - a_n b_n$
$$\Phi_{Y_n}(t) = e^{-i a_n b_n t} \Phi_{X_n}(a_n t) = e^{-i a_n b_n t}
{\left(\frac{\lambda}{\lambda - i a_n t}\right)}^n$$

We will find $a_n, b_n$ such that $\log\Phi_{Y_n}(t) \to \log\Phi_{\mathcal N(0,
1)}(t) = -\frac12 t^2$. Let's assume for a moment that $|a_n| < |\lambda / t|$:
this allows us to expand the logarithm in $(1)$. We will verify this assumption
later. We have:
$$\require{cancel}\begin{align*}
\log\Phi_{Y_n}(t) &= -i a_n b_n t + n\left(\cancel{\log \lambda} -
\cancel{\log\lambda} - \log(1 - i a_n t)\right) = \tag1\\
&= -i a_n b_n t - n\left(-i\frac{t}{\lambda}a_n - i^2\frac{t^2}{\lambda^2}
a_n^2 + \mathcal O(a_n^3)\right) =\\
&= -i a_n b_n t + in\frac{t}{\lambda}a_n -\frac{t^2}{\lambda^2} n
a_n^2 + \mathcal O(na_n^3)
\end{align*}$$

Now, the first two terms has to cancel out or go to zero, the third one must
converge to $-\frac12t^2$ and it has to be $\mathcal O(n a_n^3) \to 0$.

From the third one, we deduce
$$a_n = \frac{\lambda}{\sqrt{2n}}$$
and this also satisfies the fourth condition. Condition $(1)$ also holds
eventually. Since the second term does not go to zero, the only hope is that
the first two terms cancel out. Plugging in $a_n$ we find
$$b_n = \frac{n}{\lambda}$$
and we are done.

---

**Question**: I'm fairly confident the proof is correct, but I'd like to know
for sure. On the other hand, I'm wary of its length. The question comes from a
past exam and maybe I'm missing something simple to solve it in a shorter way?

**EDIT**: A now deleted answer suggested to use the CLT. I think that's the correct way to solve the problem, but I get a different answer for $a_n$ and $b_n$. Since the Gamma distribution, with a natural number as first parameter, is a sum of exponentials, we have that $X_n = \sum_{i = 1}^n W_i$, with $W_i \sim \text{Exp}(\lambda)$. Now, applying the CLT,
$$\sqrt n(\bar W_n - \lambda^{-1}) \xrightarrow{d} \mathcal N(0, \lambda^{-2})$$
therefore
$$\sqrt{n}\lambda(\bar W_n - \lambda^{-1}) \xrightarrow{d} \mathcal N(0, 1)$$
Since $\bar W_n = \frac1n X_n$, with a bit of algebra we find
$$\frac{\lambda}{\sqrt n}\left(X_n - \frac{n}{\lambda}\right) \xrightarrow{d} \mathcal N(0, 1)$$
giving $a_n = \lambda / \sqrt{n}$ and $b_n = n/\lambda$. But $a_n$ is different than what I obtained above. So **where's the error**?

Comment: $\log(1+x) = x - \color{red}{\frac12} x^2 +\dots$, hence the discrepancy. It seems everything else is ok.

Comment: @zhoraster Ahh thank you so much for finding that small mistake! So the second, easier method gave the correct answer.

Comment: See answer on https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/330952/99274